# Eclipse, generate code from function's arguments

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a constructor and already have class properties encapsulated via setters and getters in the class.

Now I am creating the constructor, with near 5 parameters.

Is there a key combination to create the following inside the constructor?

```
this.setParam1(param1)
this.setParam2(param2)
this.setParam3(param3)
...
```

Comment: Not by default, no,  IIRC.

Comment: Source -> Generate Constructor Using Fields?

Answer (score 1):

No. Eclipse can generate the template but cannot generate body.

Answer (score 1):

It's not directly possible.

When right-clicking the class, you can select `Source -> Generate Constructor using Fields...` to generate a constructor automatically. However, it will assign the field values directly (and not use existing setters).

Another option would be to *first* generate the constructor, as described above, and then right-click each field, and select `Refactor -> Encapsulate Field...`. This refactoring has the option to replace direct assignments (like the one that have been used in the constructor) with calls to the corresponding setter methods.